# Are there "necessary" conditions for a solution to the multivariate, truncated Hausdorff moment problem?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, statistics, probability-theory, stochastic-analysis

I am looking for NECESSARY conditions for a solution to the multivariate, truncated Hausdorff moment problem (i.e., conditions under which a given finite sequence of numbers is the sequence of first (cross) moments of a multivariate distribution on a $[0,1]^n$). Does anybody know relevant references? any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried generalizing from the univariate case? The nec and suff condition there is that a Hankel matrix formed using the sequence is positive semi-definite.

Comment: @Michael: thanks for your comment. yes, I tried to work with the Hankel matrices, but did not succeed in coming up with anything useful. any suggestions? I would appreciate any help! many thanks!